# How to display alert without background and application title?

Tags: android, dialog, themes

I am new to android. I just create one application it download the file from the mail attachment. When we try to open a file my application will give an alert dialog. But it gives the alert, behind that it shows a black background with my application title bar. I don’t want to display that background and title. I wish to display the alert only. Is there any possibility to do like this?

note:
Alert with no background means i wish to show like a mobile alert.In the download folder there will be a list of downloaded files if i select any one of the file it show the alert with the file list background

Comment: no background = transparent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set [android:theme](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme) in your Android Manifest to change the type of "window" you want to display.

In your AndroidManifest.xml you will set the android:theme to Theme.Dialog like the following:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Comment: I wish to show the alert with textbox . In that screen background i wish to display the phone screen(Before selection what screen is displayed that screen) I wish to display that alert "look like" default alert ask by the phone

Comment: I have updated my answer to show you exactly how you would set your theme so it looks like the alert dialog

Comment: Thank you Ryan Conrad.It's working but in that alert it shows the package also(com.mytheme).

Comment: what do you mean it shows the package? in the title? 

try add android:label="my title" to the activity.